# Use of arguments causing function to always return false

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I would like to sum the args of my function if and only if the two args are numbers (hence my first function).

```
function checkNum() {
 var num = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  if (typeof arguments[i] !== 'number') {
   return false;
  } 
 }
 return true;
}

function addTogether() {
  var num = 100; 
  if ( checkNum() ) { 
    return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
  } else {
    return undefined;
 }
}
addTogether(2, "");
```

However my second function performs the sum no matter what the args values are. Any hints on how to fix this ?

Comment: Don't ever use the `arguments` object like that. Declare your parameters explicitly, and *pass* them explicitly as arguments, so you'll quickly notice what didn't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`checkNum()` isn't declared to explicitly take any arguments (which implies to anyone looking at the function that none are expected) and you are not sending any when you call it, so `arguments.length` is always 0, you never enter into your loop body and you always return `true`.

Your second function is called by passing two arguments, so your references to `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]` are valid there. But, even still, the use of `arguments` isn't really meant for all argument passing.

It's best to set up your functions with named parameters and then you can access them via those names. The use of `arguments` (while valid), is not encouraged as the default mechanism for accessing arguments. It's generally used for validation (ensure that the correct amount of parameters were passed to the function before the function attempts to operate on them, for example).

Also, it's best to test for numbers with a regular expression because `typeof` can "lie" to you. For example:

```js
 // Would you ever think that not a number is of type "number"?!
 console.log(typeof NaN === "number");
```

Now, depending on your criteria for "number", there are two ways you could go.

1. Only numeric ***digits*** are allowed (i.e. 6 is allowed, "6" is not)

```js
// It's better for this function to test one number
// at a time, so you can react to that particular
// success or failure
function checkNum(num) {
  // No loop and no if/then needed, just return
  // whether the argument is a number, but don't
  // test for typeof number because typeof NaN === "number"
  // Use a regular expression instead
  var reg = /[0-9]+$/;    // digits or strings of characters that are from 0 - 9
  
  // Test for only digits not numbers passed as strings 
  // For example 6 is good, "6" is bad. Here, the use of "typeof"
  // is safe because you are also testing that the input is digits
  // or characters from 0 to 9 (NaN wouldn't pass this test)
  return reg.test(num) && typeof num === "number";  // true or false will be returned
}

function addTogether(val1, val2) {
  // Test each input, independantly so that you can react more granularly
  if ( checkNum(val1) && checkNum(val2) ) { 
    return val1 + val2;
  } 
  
  // It's not necessary to have an "else" that returns undefined because
  // that's what will happen as long as you don't return anything else.
}
console.log(addTogether(2, ""));  // undefined
console.log(addTogether(2, 6));   // 8
console.log(addTogether(2, "6")); // undefined because "6" is a string, not a digit
```

2. Numeric digits **and** numeric ***characters*** are allowed (i.e. 6 and "6" are allowed). In this case, you'd need to ensure that numeric characters get converted to numbers before addition is done so you get mathematical addition and not string concatenation.

```js
// It's better for this function to test one number
// at a time, so you can react to that particular
// success or failure
function checkNum(num) {
  // No loop and no if/then needed, just return
  // whether the argument is a number, but don't
  // test for typeof number because typeof NaN === "number"
  // Use a regular expression instead
  var reg = /[0-9]+$/;    // digits or strings that are from 0 - 9
  
  // Test for only digits and numbers passed as strings
  return reg.test(num);  // true or false will be returned
}


function addTogether(val1, val2) {
  if ( checkNum(val1) && checkNum(val2) ) {    
    // If checkNum returns true for numeric characters as well as digits, then
    // you'd need to ensure that the characters get converted to numbers so that
    // you get mathmatical addition and not string concatenation. That would be done like this:
    return +val1 + +val2
  } 
  // It's not necessary to have an "else" that returns undefined because
  // that's what will happen as long as you don't return anything else.
}
console.log(addTogether(2, ""));  // undefined
console.log(addTogether(2, 6));   // 8
console.log(addTogether(2, "6")); // 8 because "6" is converted to 6, not a string of "6"
```

Comment: `checkNum()` does not need to explicitly declare parameters. `arguments` is a valid method by which to obtain parameters passed to JavaScript functions. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: @KyleSposato Yeah, but `arguments` will be empty in this case

Comment: @KyleSposato I didn't say that `arguments` wasn't a valid way to access the arguments. I explained that in the OPs case, none were passed to `checkNum()` and so `arguments.length` will always be 0. I thought that was pretty clear.

Comment: @BrettBeatty Yes, but it is invalid to say "checkNum() doesn't take any arguments"

Comment: @KyleSposato I'm simply saying that the function doesn't explicitly declare any parameters, which is generally an indication of how it is to be used. The fact that JavaScript allows you to access parameters regardless of whether the signature specifies them is not card blanche to write functions that way.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yeah, I see that. But you pointed it out as if that was something causing the issue, which its not.

Comment: Why not checkNum(val1,val2) ?

Comment: @Jonasw Sure, why not? I don't think I said no to that.

Comment: @scott marcus isnt that what the question is about?

Comment: @Jonasw I think my answer explains the problem and provides a solution for it.

Comment: @Jonasw Answer updated for clarity and completeness.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I really appreciate your detailed answer to my question. I have a better understanding of your code now. Many thanks

Comment: It seems I cannot upvote until I reach 15 reps. I am super new in this platform.

Answer (score 1):

The `arguments` array, as evaluated within `checkNum`, contains the arguments passed to `checkNum`.  But you aren't passing any arguments to `checkNum`.  Try changing the if statement to

```
if ( checkNum(arguments[0], arguments[1]) )
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't passing any arguments to `checkNum`.  You can fix this with `apply`:

```
// ...
if (checkNum.apply(this, arguments)) {
// ...
```

**Edit**: That would allow you to check any number of arguments passed to `addTogether`. If you only want to allow for two arguments, you can used named parameters:

```
function checkNum(a, b) {

    return typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number';
}

function addTogether(a, b) {

    if (checkNum(a, b)) return a + b;
    else return undefined; // line not needed
}

addTogether(2, "");
```

Comment: Any explanation behind the downvote? Is `apply` discouraged?  I've never had problems with it.